# Given a boolean array of a size which is all true, how would i set all values to be false by only using recursion?

Tags: c++, recursion

```
void resetLog(bool log[], int size){
    if(size < 0){
    log[size] = false;
    }
    else{
        resetLog(log, --size);
    }
}
```

here's what I have so far, would really appreciate feedback

Comment: So, when `size` becomes negative, what exactly do you expect to accomplish by setting `log[-1]` to `false`? Have you [discussed this problem with your rubber duck](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rubber_duck_debugging), yet?

Comment: Why on earth do you use recursion instead of a simple loop which would be faster and leaner and cleaner?

Comment: If `size < 0`??

Comment: As Varshavchik says, think about the problem carefully. Your if statement is a problem. Out of interest, why on Earth do you actually want to do this by recursion? Is it a homework problem?

Comment: Where's the clear problem statement?

Comment: @ChristianHackl, in the title?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: OK, and where's the problem?

Comment: @ChristianHackl, if you read the code, you'll see that it will segfault.

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: Actually, no executable will be produced because there is no `main` function. Seriously, though, how can you know it will segfault? What if the OP calls it with a negative argument? And even if not, endless recursion does not necessarily result in a segfault (which is an implementation-specific and OS-specific aspect). Of course, the point I am obviously trying to make is that the question misses an MCVE and a clear explanation about what exactly doesn't work. It doesn't help that I know the answer by looking at the code. The problem must be in the question, not in the answer.

Comment: @ChristianHackl, you can't assume reasonable inputs? Why must you be a hard-ass on a newbie? Do you think that there are too many people asking novice C++ questions so we should be shutting them down?

Comment: @ThomasMcLeod: I don't have anything against beginner questions, but they require an MCVE. Otherwise, they don't add much value to Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Archimaredes yes, it is for a homework

Comment: @SamVarshavchik I should really invest in a rubber duck, thanks for your insight, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

```
void reset_bools( bool* start, bool* finish ){
  bool* mid = start + (finish-start)/2;
  if (mid==finish) return;
  *mid=false;
  reset_bools( start, mid );
  reset_bools( ++mid, finish );
}
```

This operates on a half open interval.

Comment: This is great, but OP probably wants a linear solution.

Answer (score 1):

```
void invertLog(bool[] log, int size)
{
    if(size == 0) return;
    log[--size] = false;
    invertLog(log, size);
}
```

Simple and classic `decrease and conquer` style recursion!  :D

Comment: works perfectly! thank you

Comment: No problem! Just make sure you use such `homework problems` to enhance your recursive style thinking. Always use the simplest solution to a problem. Note that a non-recursive counting loop algorithm is `easier to read`, `faster in execution`, `takes fewer stack frames` and `can be parallelized effortlessly`!  :)

Answer (score -1):

Only recursions

```
void resetLog(void* log, int asize)
{   
    __asm {
          push esi    
          cmp asize, 0
          jle stop
          mov esi, log
          add esi, asize
          dec esi         
          mov [esi], 0  
          pop esi
          jmp recurs
stop:
          pop esi
          jmp toend
recurs:   
          mov  eax, asize
          dec  eax
          push eax  
          mov  eax, log  
          push eax 
          call resetLog
          add esp, 8
toend:    
    }
    return;
}
```

Look how stack is overloaded, step by step

"Normal" code (no stack overheating)

```
void resetLog(void* log, int asize)
{   
    __asm
    {
          push ecx
          push esi
          mov ecx, log
          mov esi, ecx
          add esi, asize
    next:      
          dec esi
          cmp esi, ecx
          jl  stop
          mov [esi], 0
          jmp next
    stop:
          pop esi
          pop ecx
    }
    return;
}
```

Comment: Not recursive. Can you make it recursive?

Comment: Sure. Look at new code

Comment: Is this a joke? Question is tagged c++

Comment: Nope. I just use all functionality of c++. In my examples you can see, that the simple recursive code has a lot of underwater stones.

Comment: Assumes Intel, however.

Comment: You can eliminate one jmp by placing stop label after recurs block. Also no need to double pop stack on return, better to sub immediate on esp.

Comment: Very controversial statement about the `pop` instruction. But I changed it to `add esp`. About the label, I think it should be there just to not unbalance the operations with the stack